# Makefile machit.vim doesn't work

Tags: vim, makefile, match

Given the following simple Makefile:

```
#Makiefile
ifeq(,)
else
endif
```

According to [this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-to-jump-between-ifeq-and-endif-in-Makefile-td1185360.html), it's enough to just include this matchit.vim file, which could be found among bundled plugins.

Unfortunately, it doesn't for me. Originally, I thought my other plugins might be conflicting with matchit. However, empty setup of vim doesn't work either. According to the doc of matchit, it requires b:match_words to cycle through them. Since matchit.vim is one global plugin, the b:match_words is defined in the corresponding file type plugin. verified in vim.vim, that could be found in standard runtime directory.

Am I missing something?

PS: Right now, I have to add this to my local make.vim to make it work.

```
#make.vim
let b:match_words='\<ifeq\>:\<else\>:\<endif\>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ingo Karkat Thanks for the info. I have sent the path to Bram Moolenaar. Hopefully, it will appear in the next release. If anyone is eager, try to put this in your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/make.vim`.

```
" matchit.vim
if exists("loaded_matchit")
  let b:match_words =
    \ '\<if\(n\)\=\(eq\|def\)\>:\<else\>:\<endif\>,' .
    \ '\<define\>:\<endef\>'
endif
```

PS: Due the order of vim scripts are loaded, `~/.vim/ftplugin` is loaded before standard ftplugin, so it's preferred to put customized ftplugin in the `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` directory, if one just want to build ftplugin on top of standard ftplugin.

Thank @pevik for fixing the missing comma. Not sure why the change is rejected, but I added it manually.

Comment: I fixed missing comma, that's why I added PPS (to be able to change a text)

Answer (score 2):

The filetype for Makefiles is `make`. In my recent `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/make.vim` (dated `2006 Jun 17`), there is no definition for `b:match_words`.

Therefore, you indeed have to add the definitions to your own configuration, preferably in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/make.vim`.

If you think this is generally useful and should be included by default, you could send a patch to the script's maintainer (Bram Moolenaar).